# Как добавить в уже существующий JSON файл аналогичные по структуре JSON данные?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, запись

Делаю запрос в ВК (реквест на 10-100 запросов постов), ответ приходит в формате JSON, записываю его в свой файл.

```
def write_file(data):
    with open('posts98.json', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        json.dump(data["response"]["items"], file, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Мне нужно, чтобы при следующем запросе, если приходит другой data["response"]["items"], данные записались в уже существующий JSON.

1. Если я делаю просто дозапись в этот же файл, то сам JSON ломается, так как его структура ломается;
2. Пытался сделать через добавление с лист / словарь, но не смог.

Реализация запроса:

```
def req():
    search = '#поиск'
    token = '*************'
    r = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/newsfeed.search?user_id=7693331&v=5.126&access_token=' + token,
                      params={'q': search,
                              'count': 1,
                              'extended': 1,  # 1, если необходимо получить информацию о пользователе
                                                 # или сообществе, разместившем запись. По умолчанию: 0.
                              token: token,
                              'start_from': 0}
    )
    write_file(r.json())
```

Сам JSON такого формата:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 24660,
      "date": 1608049868,
      "owner_id": -83039408,
      "from_id": -83039408,
      "post_type": "post",
      "text": "%;№%;№",
      "marked_as_ads": 0,
      "attachments": [
        {
          "type": "photo",
          "photo": {
            "album_id": -7,
        .....
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

Предложу, как вариант, создать файл-шаблон:

```
import json

data = {"items": []}
with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

в цикле вычитывать из него данные

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

полученный ответ дописывать (словари из 'items')

```
data = data['items'].append(r['items'])
```

и сохранять снова в файл...

Answer (score 3):

Структура вашего JSON файла не позволит **дописывать** данные в конец, т.к.   список должен быть завершен (иметь `]` в конце). Тоже самое относится к закрытию словаря `}`.

Соответственно с такой структурой JSON придется парсить весь JSON файл, добавлять данные в `"items"` и перезаписывать JSON.

Пример:

```
{
  "items": [
    {"id": 24660, "date": 1608049868},
    {"id": 24661, "date": 1608049999},
  ]
}
```

если дописать в конец этого JSON файла еще одну запись - то JSON будет сломан:

```
{
  "items": [
    {"id": 24660, "date": 1608049868},
    {"id": 24661, "date": 1608049999},
  ]
}
,{"id": 24662, "date": 1609056111}
```